# SQL Running Total reset after x amount

Tags: sql, sql-server, cumulative-sum

I am running a query of the number of times a person carpools during the year, broken down by quarter.  Every time the person carpools 20 times, they are eligible to be paid.  The carpool numbers continue to accrue throughout the year but are only paid out once per quarter.

I have data like this:

```
+-------+-----+--------+----+
|quarter|value|RunTotal|Paid|
+-------+-----+--------+----+
|Jan-Mar|19.0 |19.0    |0.00|
+-------+-----+--------+----+
|Apr-Jun|2.0  |21.0    |1.00|
+-------+-----+--------+----+
|Jul-Sep|0.0  |21.0    |0.00|
+-------+-----+--------+----+
|Oct-Dec|0.0  |21.0    |0.00|
+-------+-----+--------+----+
```

As shown, they did not get a check in the first quarter.  However, they did in the second.  I can calculate the running total fine.  But, I need to do a running total in the Paid column, minus any previous payouts.  Please take a look and give me some help.

```
DECLARE @SalesTbl TABLE (quarter varchar(250), value decimal(18,1), RunningTotal decimal(18,1), earned money)
DECLARE @RunningTotal decimal(18,1), @earned money
SET @RunningTotal = 0
SET @earned = 0

INSERT INTO @SalesTbl 
    SELECT CASE DatePart(q, c.date) 
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Jan-Mar' 
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Apr-Jun' 
    WHEN 3 THEN 'Jul-Sep' 
    WHEN 4 THEN 'Oct-Dec' END AS quarter,
    IsNULL(Sum(t.value),0) AS value,
    null,
    0
FROM @calendar c
LEFT OUTER JOIN events e ON (DatePart(q, c.date) = DatePart(q, e.eventDate) AND e.employeeID = @employeeID AND e.eventType = 'CP' AND Year(eventDate) = @year)
LEFT JOIN types t ON t.typeID = e.eventType
GROUP BY DatePart(q, c.date)

UPDATE @SalesTbl 
SET @RunningTotal = RunningTotal = @RunningTotal + value, @earned = earned = Floor(@RunningTotal/20) - (SELECT Sum(earned) FROM @SalesTbl)

FROM @SalesTbl

SELECT * FROM @SalesTbl
```

Comment: What SQL engine are you using?  It looks like SQL server, but what version?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should use SQL windowing

See the below page for an example:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx

You should partition by quarter (DatePart(q, c.date)) and SUM(t.value).
SUM(SUM(t.value)) OVER(PARTITION BY DatePart(q, c.date)) AS 'Total'